# 4G modem can send data but can not receive and at command no response

Tags: c, at-command

I have a development board equipped with a Cat.1 4G modem to control lamp。During the test, I found that the data could be sent but the response from the server or the command could not be received. Checking the TTL output log found that when the above problem occurred, the AT command could not respond. May I ask what could be the cause of this?The following is part of the TTL log information。

```
AT+CIPSEND=52

> 65020000000001970802002500000000436E1394000000003F6D8CEE000000000119000861714054084870170519102325031756

SEND OK
+IPD,15:e    ?  eZV
650200000000019708030000655A56
AT+CSQ

+CSQ: 27,99

OK
AT+CIPSEND=52

> 65020000000001980802002500000000436E1394000000003F6D8CEE00000000011B000861714054084870170519102426DB5C56

SEND OK
AT+CSQ

+CSQ: 26,99

OK
AT+CIPSEND=52
65020000000001990802002500000000436E1394000000003F6D8CEE00000000011A000861714054084870170519102526E79E56
AT+CCLK?
AT+CSQ
AT+CIPSEND=52
650200000000019A0802002500000000436E1394000000003F6D8CEE00000000011A000861714054084870170519102626E06956
AT+CSQ
AT+CIPSEND=52
650200000000019B0802002500000000436E1394000000003F6D8CEE00000000011A000861714054084870170519102727DCFB56
AT+CSQ
AT+CIPSEND=52
650200000000019C0802002500000000436E1394000000003F6D8CEE00000000011A0008617140540848701705191028272BC756
AT+CSQ
AT+CIPSEND=52
650200000000019D0802002500000000436E1394000000003F6D8CEE00000000011A000861714054084870170519102927D69556
AT+CIPSEND=52
650200000000019E0802002500000000436E1394000000003F6D8CEE00000000011A000861714054084870170519102A28916656
AT+CCLK?
AT+CSQ
AT+CIPSEND=52
650200000000019F0802002500000000436E1394000000003F6D8CEE00000000011A000861714054084870170519102B286C3456
AT+CSQ
AT+CIPSEND=52
65020000000001A00802002500000000436E1394000000003F6D8CEE00000000011A000861714054084870170519102C28056F56
AT+CSQ
AT+CIPSEND=52
65020000000001A10802002500000000436E1394000000003F6D8CEE00000000011A000861714054084870170519102D2939FD56
AT+CSQ
the 10 times heartbeat connection fails, close the scenarior
```

When the above problem occurs, it can only be solved by restarting the 4G modem or power off and restarting, but now I want to know why this problem occurs

Comment: What does this question have to do with C?